# How to hide control if entity set is empty

Tags: sapui5

I get from backend via OData service `IDNumber` (an EntitySet).
On frontend, all IDs are shown but if the `IDNumber` set is empty, I want to hide the `ComboBox` (`visible="false"`).
I have no idea how to handle this.

```xml
<ComboBox id="cbIDNumber"
  items="{/IDNumber}"
  visible="{
    path: '{/IDNumber}',
    formatter: '.formatter.formatVisible'
  }"
/>
```

In `formatter.js`, the passed parameter is `null`.
How can I get some input I can work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an event `dataReceived` that will be triggered if your IDNumber list is loaded.

```xml
<ComboBox id="cbIDNumber" 
    items="{
        path: '/IDNumber',
        events: {
            dataReceived: '.onDataReceived'
        }
    }" />
```

In your controller you can then implement an event handler:

```js
onDataReceived: function(oEvent) {
    const oData = oEvent.getParameter("data");
    const aResults = oData.results;
    const bIsVisible = aResults.length > 0;

    const oCB = this.byId("cbIDNumber");
    oCB.setVisible(bIsVisible);
}
```